# I want to export mount path as NFS share

Tags: mount, nfs

can any one suggest me the procedure?

below volume with btrfs filesystem shoulb be exported as NFS share
/dev/sdb on /btrfs type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,space_cache)

Answer (score 0):

You should read some howto e. g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo, especially the section https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#Installation_and_Configuration

This should get you quite far already. Feel free to ask more specific questions if you are still having trouble setting up NFS shares.